# wordpress sub taxonomies are not showing properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display only 1st level of sub taxonomies, below is my code,it's just not working, can anyone please tell whats wrong with my code?? Many thanks.

```
<?php

$term_id = 31;
$taxonomy_name = 'kosher_category';

$args = array('child_of' => $term_id, 'parent' => $term_id);
$termchildren = get_terms($taxonomy_name, $args );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Subcats are **empty**? Add `hide_empty` with `0`!

Comment: No, the sucats are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Add `hide_empty`.

```
<?php
    $term_id        = 31;
    $taxonomy_name  = 'kosher_category';
    $args           = array(
        'child_of'      => $term_id,
        'parent'        => $term_id,
        'hide_empty'    => false    // ADDED
    );
    $termchildren   = get_terms($taxonomy_name, $args );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($termchildren AS $child) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $child, $taxonomy_name);
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: I still have the same error: Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/allsongrayce.com/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1026

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/allsongrayce.com/wp-content/themes/polo360/taxonomy.php on line 21